# It is possible to get any keystrokes in application regardless of active window?

Tags: .net, winforms, keypress, mdi

My MDI application handles regular keystrokes (A-Z, 0-9 etc.) in [keypress](/questions/tagged/keypress) handler of Main window with `KeyPreview = true`. It filters some sequences of incoming characters, hiding them from subsequent `KeyPress` handlers. This works fine in MDI windows, but the Main window's `KeyPress` is not invoked if modal window is active (because Main form is no longer focused). I open modal windows through simple `ShowDialog()`.

Is there some way to universally catch and filter KeyPress events regardless of which application window has the focus (including modal windows?)

I'm searching for **handling of KeyPresses on application level, not global level**. => I don't want to be notified of KeyPresses if the application doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to universally catch and filter KeyPress events
>   regardless of which application window has the focus (including modal
>   windows?) I'm searching for handling of KeyPresses on application
>   level ...

This can be accomplished via [IMessageFilter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's a quick example:

```
public partial class MainMdiParent : Form
{

    private MyFilter MF = new MyFilter();

    public MainMdiParent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainMdiParent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MF.EscapeKey += MF_EscapeKey;
        Application.AddMessageFilter(MF);

        childA a = new childA();
        a.MdiParent = this;
        a.Show();

        a = new childA();
        a.MdiParent = this;
        a.Show(); 
    }

    private void MF_EscapeKey()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escape Key Trapped in Main Form");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form dlg = new Form();
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }

}

public class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
{

    public delegate void EscapeKeyDelegate();
    public event EscapeKeyDelegate EscapeKey;

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg )
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
                {
                    case (int)Keys.Escape:
                        if (EscapeKey != null)
                        {
                            EscapeKey();
                        }
                        return true; // suppress it?
                        break;
                }
                break;

        }

        return false; // returning false allows messages to be processed normally
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this answer, I didn't even think of preprocessing the wndproc. I guess the op has two good options now :)

Comment: @caesay - yes I have :) I've seen this concept before but I thought its scope is form, not an application. It also allows to handle all other message types, what can be useful.

Comment: @miroxlav: let us know which way you went with in the end.

Comment: @caesay – it looks I'll go with filtering because it fulfills well principle of single point-of-access to the functionality and it will allow me to keep `ShowDialog()` calls as they are. Now they are scattered in 154 files, about 5 occurrences in each. Changing this could be quite expensive. It's legacy code at the project I joined...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that when you call `ShowDialog`, your main UI thread will stop dispatching messages. Look at this simplified message loop:

```
while(true) 
{
    Message m;
    GetMessage(out m);
    // if close button pressed etc.
    if (m.Msg == WM_QUIT) break;
    DispatchMessage(m);
}
```

When you activate your dialog, this is executed in DispatchMessage and starts a new message loop that is similar. Because of this new loop, the loop from your main window is blocked on that DispatchMessage call, and will not process any keyboard messages. It is tricky working with multiple UI loops and for that reason I would recommend using the regular `Show()` message (which will not block your main application loop) and find another way to direct the users focus to that window.

There is a p/invoke call that I have used in the past which sets the parent window as disabled and directs user focus to the child window, it is almost identical to the behavior of the `ShowDialog` call, but without blocking the thread. What you would do is set the owner of your child form, call the regular `Show()` method, and finally set the enabled state of your parent window to false. You can do the later with this code:

```
const int GWL_STYLE   = -16;
const int WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

void SetWindowEnabled(Form form, bool enabled)
{
    SetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_STYLE) &
                  ~WS_DISABLED | (enabled ? 0 : WS_DISABLED));
}
```

Touching on your comment about stacked model windows, I think this is possible but it is important to make sure that the native method is called to re-enable the parent window when the dialog is closed. I would implement an extension method that looks something like this:

```
public static class FormsExtensions
{
    public static Task<bool> ShowNativeDialog(this Form child, Form owner)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        child.Show();
        SetWindowEnabled(owner, false);
        child.Closed += (sender, args) => { 
            SetWindowEnabled(owner, true);
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

And usage would look something like this:

```
DialogForm dialog = new DialogForm();
await dialog.ShowNativeDialog(this);
```

By using await, you can stop the execution flow without blocking the UI messaging loop.

Comment: Interesing answer. Let me try to implement this approach... I'm curious to see whether this will work well even with stacked modal windows (modal dialog open from modal dialog).

Answer (score 1):

according to msdn the system sends keyboard messages only to the foreground thread, does the modal windows start in another thread ? 
if yes you can just message  the main  from the modal window thread with some simple thread messaging using the same handles you used in the main window  form  ,
now if you don't have any idea of what thread is .... you can always learn

here are some nice articles that can help you 
[about keyboards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx)

[about threads and msgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590(v=vs.85).aspx)

additional note:
you can always use [sendkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) function to send keys to another target , if needed

Edit: Showdialog is a blocking  asynchronous call , it "freezes" the thread and other windows and returns only when the window  that launched was closed , this is why the handles don't respond when you have modal window activated

Comment: I'm using classic `ShowDialog()` to open modal windows. At the moment I'm not sure whether it opens modal window in separate thread.

Comment: ha this is it man , the showDialog is issue here , when launched it disables all other windows , so the main window is unable to do anything , you should find another way on launching the modal window

Comment: When a Window class is instantiated, it is not visible by default. ShowDialog shows the window, disables all other windows in the application, and returns only when the window is closed. This type of window is known as a modal window, directly from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ edit: this behavior of `ShowDialog()` can be actually observed in the app. Your idea given in the answer (routing keystrokes back to Main form) has something in it. I'll test it. Before I need to find out how to do `ShowDialog()` in another thread, but still keeping shown dialog modal (blocking other windows of the same app).